# How can I deal with given situtaion related to Hardware change

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, fpga

I am maintaining a Production code related to FPGA device .Earlier resisters on FPGA are of 32 bits and read/write to these registers are working fine.But Hardware is changed and so did the FPGA device and with latest version of FPGA device we have trouble in read and write to FPGA register .After some R&D we came to know FPGA registers are no longer 32 bit ,it is now 31 bit registers and same has been claimed by FPGA device vendor.

So there is need to change small code as well.Earlier we were checking that address of registers are 4 byte aligned or not(because registers are of 32 bits)now with current scenario we have to check address are 31 bit aligned.So for the same we are going to check
if the most significant bit of the address is set (which means it is not a valid 31 bit).
I guess we are ok here.

Now second scenario is bit tricky for me.
if read/write for multiple registers that is going to go over the 0x7fff-fffc (which is the maximum address in 31 bit scheme) boundary, then have to handle request carefully.

Reading and Writing for multiple register takes length as an argument which is nothing but number of register to be read or write.

For example, if the read starts with 0x7fff-fff8, and length for the read is 5. Then actually, we can only read 2 registers (which is 0x7fff-fff8, and 0x7fff-fffc).

Now could somebody suggest me some kind of pseudo code to handle this scenario

Some think like below

```
while(lenght>1)
{
  if(!(address<<(lenght*31) <= 0x7fff-fffc))
   {
     length--;
   }
}
```

I know it is not good enough but something in same line which I can use.

**EDIT**

I have come up with a piece of code which may fulfill my requirement

```
 int count;

 Index_addr=addr;

 while(Index_add <= 7ffffffc)
 {   
  /*Wanted to move register address to next register address,each register is 31 bit   wide and are at consecutive location. like 0x0,0x4 and 0x8 etc.*/

  Index_add=addr<<1; // Guess I am doing wrong here ,would anyone correct it.

  count++;

 }

 length=count;
```

Comment: Just as a point of terminology, a 31-bit address space isn't referred to as "31-bit aligned". It's just a 31-bit address space, with address ranging from `0x00000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`. Also, I'mn not sure I understand the syntax in your C code with `<= 0x7fff-fffc`. I assume you mean `0x7ffffffc`?

Comment: What is the data type of `address` (how is it declared)?

Comment: Well @mbratch may be terminology wise I went wrong ,we can say 31-bit boundry check or something else.Yes you are right its simply 0x7ffffffc .

Comment: Could it be that the registers themselves are still 4 byte aligned but they only contain 31 bits? You would still read them into a 4 byte int but the high order bit would be useless/undefined.

Comment: Sorry @mbratch for the delayed response.Both address and length are defined as uint32_t.

Comment: *"FPGA registers are memory mapped from 0x0000_0000 to 0x7ffffffc "* -- So there are 536,870,912 registers in this FPGA?  Are these addresses in physical or virtual memory space?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure I'm interpreting the given scenario correctly. But here's a shot at it:

```
// Assuming "address" starts 4-byte aligned and is just defined as an integer
unsigned uint32_t address; // (Assuming 32-bit unsigned longs)

while ( length > 0 )    // length is in bytes
{
    // READ 4-byte value at "address"
    // Mask the read value with 0x7FFFFFFF since there are 31 valid bits

    // 32 bits (4 bytes) have been read
    if ( (--length > 0) && (address < 0x7ffffffc) )
        address += 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mbratch for the your response. would your code  will be perfect in a scenario where the address passed to fpga_read function is 0x7ffffffc and length is 2 here(Number of register to be read) ,But it can only read one registers ,so length parameter should cut down to one only and it then read one register starts at address 0x7ffffffc??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar I just updated my answer based upon your response to my question on data type. It should read the correct number of registers based upon the length given. So if length is 1, it should read one register. It will only read one register unless length is above 4, then it will read more than one, as needed.

Comment: Mr sawdust made quite a point here,, instead of treating the 31-bit FPGA registers as memory locations, they should be abstracted.We can't treat FPGA registers addressed as memory location,So adding 4 to an address may not work as you are expecting and why length=-4 ,can I expect it to be lenght=-1?.What you say @mbratch on same.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar, based upon your descriptions so far, I was assuming that the `length` is number of bytes read from the FPGA. Perhaps that was an invalid assumption. If it's true, then each time through the loop is a 4-byte read. Thus `length -= 4`. Regarding your other comment, the detail on how the FPGA registers are designed and mapped are not expressed in your problem statement. So it's difficult to determine completely the correct approach without that information. Are the FPGA registers memory mapped as bytes or as words? What does the hardware expect?

Comment: lenght is not the number of bytes read from FPGA ,it is actually number of register you want to read from or write to,for example if length is 2 then we can read from two register starting from the address given as one of parameter along side with length.In this scenario what changes you would like to do in your given code.FPGA registers are memory mapped from 0x0000_0000 to 0x7ffffffc where each register is of 31 bit long.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar ah ok, sorry that wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem seems to be that the program is not properly treating the FPGA registers.
Data encapsulation would help, and, instead of treating the 31-bit FPGA registers as memory locations, they should be abstracted.

The FPGA should be treated as a vector (a one-dimensional array) of registers.
The vector of *N* FPGA registers should be addressable by an `register index` in the range of 0x0000 through *N-1*.
The FPGA registers are memory mapped at `base addr`.
So the `memory address` = 4 * `FPGA register index` + `base addr`.

Access to the FPGA registers should be encapsulated by read and write procedures:

```
int read_fpga_reg(int reg_index, uint32_t *reg_valp)
{

    if (reg_index < 0 || reg_index >= MAX_REG_INDEX)
        return -1;  /*  error return */

    *reg_valp = *(uint32_t *)(reg_index << 2 + fpga_base_addr);
    return 0;
}
```

As long as MAX_REG_INDEX and fpga_base_addr are properly defined, then this code will never generate an invalid memory access.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I agree to the point you made instead of treating the 31-bit FPGA registers as memory locations, they should be abstracted.Like to know would your code  handle the second scenario I mentioned in my question,I think all we need is to cut the length parameter to some appropriate value .I would request you to explain your code a bit more,like what is reg_index and reg_valp.Max_REG_INDEX would be 0x7ffffffc if I relate to my case.